# Postgres - How to fetch escaped data from table

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql, pdo

The solution seems to be simple but I am finding it hard to get around. In the table, the sample data is as:

```
 id   |               name               |        created_time        
 -------+----------------------------------+----------------------------
41477 | women''s hostels                 | 2016-03-24 13:52:52.855116
41476 | women''s hostels                 | 2016-03-24 13:52:49.895482
41475 | women''s hostels                 | 2016-03-24 13:52:49.735788
41471 | men''s hostel                    | 2016-03-24 13:52:42.907983
41469 | women''s clothing shops          | 2016-03-24 13:52:30.666364
```

I have inserted this data using PHP's PDO prepared statements so the single quotes have been escaped properly.

Now I want to fetch the records where name exactly matches

> women's hostels

I want to accomplish this in both ways using raw SQL query and through PDO. I am trying following for both cases, but not getting any result:

Raw SQL:

```
SELECT id FROM <TABLE> where name = 'women''s hostels';
SELECT id FROM <TABLE> where name ilike 'women''s hostels';
SELECT id FROM <TABLE> where name::text = 'women''s hostels';
```

PDO:

```
$data = "women''s hostels";
$sql = "SELECT id FROM <TABLE> where name=?"; (tried all variations as above)
$stmt->execute(array($data));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The name field is defined in table as below:

```
Column    |            Type             | 
name      | character varying(255)      |
```

Please help. Let me know if anything else is needed. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no escaped data in database in the first place.

> I have inserted this data using PHP's PDO prepared statements so the single quotes have been escaped properly.

They have been not.

Were they escaped properly, you'd have the original string in database, "women's hostels". But as you have your data in database escaped, it means that escaping occurred **twice**.

So you have to hunt down and remove that superfluous escaping during **insert**.

Then select whatever data usual way. It makes no difference whether you have quotes in it or not.

Comment: Thanks @Your Common Sense! I understood the wrong  I was doing.